# display: inline-block not working

Tags: css

I made `display: inline-block` working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Ttk68/). As you can see, checkbox and text were aligned horizontally.

But it does not work on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqr4e/27/):

Actually I have `three problems` to solve here:

1. Make the checkbox and text: `Swing Equipment Also` inline with the checkbox.
2. In the right content, I have a button `Swing System` and I want it to be right aligned.
3. As you can see, I have `left` and `right` contents. They are mostly `50%` of the width, I want them to be centered. Currently it is not.

Code snippet:

HTML

```
  <li>
        <input type="checkbox" class="swing_checkbox" id="swing_equipment" /> <span id="swing_label_small">Swing Equipment Also</span>
  </li>
```

CSS:

```
#swing_label_small, #swing_equipment {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Make the checkbox and text: Swing Equipment Also inline with the checkbox.

The checkbox has a `width` set to `90%` by this css declaration...

```
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
}
```

change that to...

```
input[type=text] {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
}
```

> In the right content, I have a button Swing System and I want it to be right aligned.

First thing I noticed is you are placing a button inside a `ul`...that will not validate as proper html. I would suggest you to move it out of the `ul` because is not semantically correct. But working with what you have...adding `text-align:right` to the `ul` and then adding `text-align:right` to the child `li` should work...

```
#right_content{
    text-align:right;
}
ul#right_content > li {
    border: 0px solid green;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    text-align:left;
}
```

> As you can see, I have left and right contents. They are mostly 50% of the width, I want them to be centered. Currently it is not.

I'm not too sure what you mean...please clarify so I can modify my answer

Comment: Thanks Leo. I have updated my fiddle for the third concern. I added a red box. The contents inside that box are not centered on the red box - http://jsfiddle.net/Pqr4e/32/

Comment: @JunM It's because there is a default padding on the `ul` element. Remove that. http://jsfiddle.net/XvGK3/

Answer (score 2):

**1)** For the checkbox and text issue: apply `width: auto;` to the checkbox:

```
.swing_checkbox {
    width:auto;
}
```

The following was giving the checkbox a width of 90%, which is why the text was pushed down to the next line.

```
input {
    position: relative;
    width: 90%;
}
```

**2)** Something like this will work, I'm using inline styles here because I am lazy. Feel free to tidy that up yourself.

```
<ul class="content" id="right_content">
    <li style="text-align: right;">    <button type="button" class="swing_btn">Swing System</button></li>        
    ...
    ...
    ...
```

**3)** Use `text-align:center;` on the container, and then apply `text-align:left;` to it's inner elements. This will center block level elements with a percentage defined width. There are other ways to do this, however, if you're interested in researching them.

```
.swing_wrapper {
    text-align: center;
}

ul.content,.swing_title, {
    text-align: left;
}
```

**4)** You should also take a look at some debug tools such as [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/), it makes debugging issues like this a lot easier with it's Inspection tool.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the changes I made.

For 1) added CSS to checkbox as you make all input widht:90%;

```
input[type="checkbox"]{
    width:auto;
}
```

For 2) added a div field for clear both purpose. Then make the button float right.

HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="swing_btn">Swing System</button>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.clear{ clear:both;}
#right_content > button
{
    float:right;    
}
```

3)As your are using ul as structure. there are padding that been use for ul.

Removed the inner ul padding that ruined the structure.

```
ul  li  ul {
    padding:0px;
}
```

Gave table a margin to make it center:

```
.swing_grid, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

And finally let the content align center:

```
ul.content {
    border: 0px solid gray;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 49%;
    position: relative;
    list-style-type: none;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Here's my [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Pqr4e/30/) work.